# How to Synchronize Audio with Video Frames [Python]

Tags: python, sockets, ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I want to stream video from URL to a server via socket, which then restreams it to all clients in the room.

This code streams video frame by frame:

```py
async def stream_video(room, url):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    fps = round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret: break
        _, img_bytes = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
        img_base64 = base64.b64encode(img_bytes).decode('utf-8')
        img_data_url = f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{img_base64}"

        await socket.emit('segment', { 'room': room, 'type': 'video', 'stream': img_data_url})
        await asyncio.sleep(1/fps)
    
    cap.release()
```

And this is code for stream audio:

```py
async def stream_audio(room, url):
    sample_size = 14000
    cmd_audio = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", url,
        '-vn',
        '-f', 's16le',
        '-c:a', 'pcm_s16le',
        "-ac", "2",
        "-sample_rate","48000",
        '-ar','48000',
        "-acodec","libmp3lame",
        "pipe:1"
    ]
    proc_audio = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmd_audio, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=False
    )

    while True:
        audio_data = await proc_audio.stdout.read(sample_size)
        if audio_data:
            await socket.emit('segment', { 'room': room, 'type': 'audio', 'stream': audio_data})
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

But the problem is: how to synchronize them? **How many bytes** need to be read every second from ffmpeg so that the audio matches the frames.

I tried to do this, but the problem with the number of chunks still remained:

```py
while True:
    audio_data = await proc_audio.stdout.read(sample_size)
    if audio_data:
        await socket.emit('segment', { 'room': room, 'type': 'audio', 'stream': audio_data})

        for i in range(fps):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret: break
            _, img_bytes = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
            img_base64 = base64.b64encode(img_bytes).decode('utf-8')
            img_data_url = f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{img_base64}"

            await socket.emit('segment', { 'room': room, 'type': 'video', 'stream': img_data_url})
            await asyncio.sleep(1/fps)
```

I also tried loading a chunk of audio into pydub, but it shows that the duration of my 14000 chunk is 0.07s, which is very small. And if you increase the number of chunks for reading to 192k (as the gpt chat says), then the audio will simply play very, very quickly.
The ideal number of chunks that I was able to achieve is approximately 14000, but the audio is still not synchronous.